# Prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$ is meromorphic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

The question is prove that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$ determines a meromorphic function. So the way that I prove these kinds of questions is fix $R>0$ and prove that it is meromorphic at any disk $D(0,R)$. Then let $N>2R$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$ and $h(z)=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$. Then g is clearly meromorphic and I need to prove that h is holomorphic and then I am done. To that end I need to prove that the sum in $h$ converges uniformly.
In the previous exercises I have tried so far, I could use M-test to determine that, which here clearly doesn't work, as it's not absolutely convergent.

So I am curious on how to check uniform convergence of alternating series in complex analysis? Is there a useful test for that? Or do I have to just get my hands dirty with just proving that it is Cauchy?

I was wondering whether the following 2 statements are correct:

(i) If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{|z+n|}$ converges uniformly then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$ converges uniformly.

(ii) If f=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nf_n(x)$ a series in the real numbers and $f_n>0$ is decreasing to $0$ uniformly, then $f$ converges uniformly.

Comment: here you need a grouping of consecutive terms or using the trick $f(z)+\log 2=1/z+\sum _{n \ge 1}(-1)^n(\frac{1}{z+n}-\frac{1}{n})$ and then you get absolute convergence (hence uniform convergence on compacts avoiding the poles) that way too

Comment: There is no such thing as an alternating series of complex numbers (except when it reduces to the real case).